# Unable to load the requested file: templates/header.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, foreach

i am trying sample code for testing (learning) codeigniter but i have some error like this when i am run my project the url like http://localhost/CodeIgniter_test/todos so that folloing error is occured

An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: templates/header.php

and i take the code from this url http://www.allshorevirtualstaffing.com/how-to-develop-basic-crud-operations-in-codeigniter/#.VORuXGPWS1E

Comment: I think you may miss typing in folder name. In the code, you tried to load file from "templates" folder, but your real folder name is "template", "templates" is right, not "template"

Comment: in my case folder's first letter was capital and in code I wrote small .. it worked on local but was not working in production

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the file `header.php` in `application/views/templates` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permissions. If you overwrote those files using ftp, whih is common, you may have changed the file permissions and/or ownership without being aware.

Answer (score -1):

```
class View extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    }
    public function myview() {
        $this->load->view('templates/header.php');
        $this->load->view('templates/myview.php');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer.php');
   }
```

to load the view you have to write  example.com/index.php/view/myview
in codeigniter in application/views/templates folder you must have the above three files header.php,myview.php,footer.php